# How can I apply a filter in MongoDB find operation to check empty string?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a application built in PHP using MongoDB as a database.
Data is organized across BSON documents into a collection in MongoDB.

I need to retrieve only those documents where field containing string value is non empty value. I searched for functions equivalent to empty and strlen functions belonging to PHP language but did not get any relevant search results.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the language is. The [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) and `""` part is what is important for an non-empty string.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**,

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("someField" => array('$ne' => null)));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Badacadabra Thanks to answer question